# Size of cell elements

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell

I have five classes of data stored in a `cell`,

```
DataCell = 

[74035x14 single] [8063x14 single] [7244x14 single] [6895x14 single] [2510x14 single]
```

I want to get the prior probabilities of each class,

So want it's pretty simple,

```
SumData = 74032 + 8063 + 7244 + 6895 + 2510;
prior = [74035 8063 7244 6895 2510] / SumData;
```

I was wondering if there is a way to avoid loop and get the answer.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the counts of the `DataCell` into an array, then "nomalize" it:

```
data_counts = cellfun(@(x) size(x,1), DataCell);
prior       = data_counts / sum(data_counts(:));
```

The `data_counts(:)` is just a funny way of summing all the elements of data_counts, no matter what shape they're in.

Comment: `data_counts` would always be a vector, so that `(:)` isn't really needed I think.

Comment: @Divakar I just tested with `DataCell = {zeros(1,14), ones(2,14); zeros(3,14),ones(4,14)};  data_counts = cellfun(@(x) size(x,1), DataCell);` and I got a 2x2 result for `data_counts`. I use MATLAB R2012a.

Comment: Right that makes sense for a 2D or multidimensional cell array. I got the same results.

Comment: You can simply do `cellfun('size', DataCell, 1);`.  `cellfun` has a special mode internally if you just want to find the size of elements inside each cell in a cell array.

Comment: @rayryeng actually that is a more elegant solution than mine. You should post it! And I learned something new today: `edit cellfun` is an interesting read. :-)

Comment: @CST-Link - hahah sure, I can post, but it's really only a minor tweak in comparison to what you have.

Answer (score 2):

To add to CST-Link's answer, `cellfun` has a special flag where if you specify `'size'`, you can determine the size of of elements inside each cell in a cell array.  You simply specify which dimension you're measuring the size of and it'll return an array of elements that denote the size of each cell in a particular dimension.  It will also respect whatever the shape of your cell array was before you call `cellfun`.  For example, if you have a 2 x 2 cell array, after using `'size'`, it will return a 2 x 2 numeric matrix where each element is the size of the dimension you specified.

Therefore, do this:

```
data_counts = cellfun('size', DataCell, 1);
prior       = data_counts / sum(data_counts(:));
```

To add to the `data_counts(:)` statement, this is MATLAB's way of **unrolling a matrix**.  What this will do is that it transforms `data_counts` into a single vector, where it is composed of columns of `A` stacked on top of each other.  For example, if you had a matrix like so:

```
A  =

1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8
9  10  11  12
13  14  15  16
```

Doing `A(:)` would give you:

```
1
5
9
13
2
6
10
14
3
7
11
15
4
8
12
16
```

However, if `A` is **already a 1D array**, then this has no effect at all.  The only thing that it will do is that if your array was a row vector, this will transform the array so that it's column vector.  If it was already a column vector, then this won't change anything.  This is a neat trick to ensure that a 1D array is always a column vector.

Comment: This should be fast too!